# Disable vs. Drop Constraint

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

What is the functional difference between those two opetions?

When inserting data on a large table I personally would disable the constraint.  But does it make any difference to the drop constraint? I am disabling the constraint because otherwise inserts are pretty slow.

Comment: Disable and Enable an existing contraint is much simpler than drop and create.

Answer (score 5):

If you're doing data loads or other maintenance, it makes sense to disable rather than drop a constraint.

The idea is, if you *know* you're going to want to get that constraint back when you're done w/ the data load or maintenance, then disable it.  When you're done, you can simply enable it.

You shouldn't drop, unless you're reasonably certain you won't need that constraint in the future.  The danger of dropping rather than disabling is that you may get it slightly (or completely) wrong when you re-create the constraint.  If you simply disable, there's no danger of losing the constraint definition, as the constraint definition remains in the data dictionary.

Comment: alright got that.  but does it make any difference in  creating / enabling time?  Just from trying i would say enabling can be faster,  thats correct?  or does it make no difference?

Comment: Well, if you're just enabling, then there will be less data dictionary updates than if you're creating.  But, I would imagine that the majority of the time, whether you're enabling existing constraint or creating a new one, would be spent in validation.  So, I guess my answer is that it's (probably?) slightly more costly to create a new constraint rather than enable an existing one, but the difference is probably not enough to matter very much.  I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Beware that you may not want to "simply enable it".  For example, if you re-enable a constraint with a parallel index that index will not be rebuilt in parallel and the final degree will be set back to 1.  If I remember correctly some other index properties can get lost, perhaps compression?  Whichever method you use, make sure you test it using DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL to ensure that the indexes are exactly the same before and after.